Purchase order will not show as a payment option in admin order creation, only credit card displays as an option
Currently in my Magento 2.4.6 store, only the credit card payment option will show up as an option when I try and place an order for a customer in the admin.  I also have Purchase Order enabled as a payment method which shows up fine on the front end.  I'm using the Authroze.net CIM extension from Paradox Labs, Inc for my credit card payments (in case that matters).  I even disabled the Authorize.net payment to see if that was conflicting with something but it didn't help.  I enabled Cash On Delivery, Check/Money order as well but none of those options will show up either.
Does anyone know why all the payment options I have enabled won't show up in the admin order creation page?
I saw a post about checking protected $_canUseInternal = true; but for the module-offline-payments there isn't that line in the Purchaseorder.php file.  I added it to see what happened but it didn't change anything.  Just an FYI the Purchase Order payment method I'm using is the built-in one, not anything custom.
Thanks
